# Combining elements in the same list

Tags: c#, linq, list

suppose I have a list that comes from a database like this:

```
List<Item> list =
{
    new Item
    {
        TypeID = 2,
        Count = 5
    },
    new Item
    {
        TypeID = 2,
        Count = 7
    },
    new Item
    {
        TypeID = 5,
        Count = 2
    }
};
```

I would like to sum up all elements with the same `TypeID` so that I have a final result list with two elements only:

```
List<Item> list =
{
    new Item
    {
        TypeID = 2,
        Count = 12
    },
    new Item
    {
        TypeID = 5,
        Count = 2
    }
};
```

How can I achive this using LINQ?
Cheers
Simon

Comment: Nothing so far. Well it would be easy using `foreach` but I want to have in with LINQ.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot [link](http://athaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` to group by `TypeID` first and then do `Sum` on each group:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.TypeID)
                 .Select(g => new Item() { 
                                  TypeId = g.Key, 
                                  Count = g.Sum(x => x.Count)
                         })
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: Both answers are correct. But Cuong Le war faster... Thx a lot, exactly what I wanted to have.

Answer (score 7):

```
list.GroupBy(x=>x.TypeID)
    .Select(x=>new Item(){TypeID=x.Key,Count=x.Sum(y=>y.Count) })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq extension method Union.

```
var mergedList = list1.Union(list2).ToList();
```