# Scala: Combine some elements in a list when they have the same property

Tags: scala

How do I combine some elements in a list when they have the same property?

E.g. let say I have the following:

```
case class Foo(year: Int, amount: Int)
val list = List(Foo(2015, 10), Foo(2015, 15), Foo(2019, 55))
```

How do I transform `list` into `List(Foo(2015, 25), Foo(2019, 55))` the Scala way?

As you can see both `Foo(2015, 10)` and `Foo(2015, 15)` are merged into `List(Foo(2015, 25)`.

Similar question with [Combining elements in the same list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637448/combining-elements-in-the-same-list) but that's for C#/LINQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on `Scala 2.13`+, consider using [`groupMapReduce`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.0/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#groupMapReduce[K,B](key:A=%3EK)(f:A=%3EB)(reduce:(B,B)=%3EB):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,B]):

```
list.groupMapReduce(_.year)(_.amount)(_ + _).
  map{ case (y, a) => Foo(y, a) }
// res1: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Foo] = List(Foo(2019,55), Foo(2015,25))
```

Comment: Or `...map(Foo.tupled)`

Answer (score 2):

Use `groupBy` to arrange `list` by `year`, then map over the results to get it in the proper shape and `sum` the `amount` of each `Foo`.

```
scala> list.groupBy(foo => foo.year).map(m => Foo(m._1, m._2.map(foo => foo.amount).sum))
res5: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Foo] = List(Foo(2015,25), Foo(2019,55))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a *Refactoring* of *Brian*'s answer. I use *Pattern Matching* to properly name the values.

I think it helps read the code.

```
list
  .groupBy{case Foo(year, _) => year}
  .map{ case (year, foos) => 
     Foo(year, 
         foos.map{ case Foo(_, amount) => amount}.sum)
  }
```